# I am getting this error TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'map' of object '#<QueryCursor>' 2022-02-19T12:38:49.101286+00:00 app[web.1]:

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, heroku, webpack

I am trying to deploy my node.js app for weeks but I am not able to deploy it, Please can someone please help me to deploy this, I have done everything, but still Heroku says application error.
Please help to solve this issue, I am getting these error in my Heroku logs

```
Starting process with command `node index.js`
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101275+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cursor/QueryCursor.js:144
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101284+00:00 app[web.1]: QueryCursor.prototype.map = function(fn) {
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101285+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101285+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101286+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'map' of object '#<QueryCursor>'
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101286+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cursor/QueryCursor.js:144:27)
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101286+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101286+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:10)
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101287+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101287+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101287+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101288+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101288+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:12:21)
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101288+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101288+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:10)
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101292+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-19T12:38:49.101292+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v17.5.0
2022-02-19T12:38:49.222099+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-02-19T12:38:49.270154+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-02-19T12:38:49.273378+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-02-19T12:38:52.851143+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692822+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cursor/QueryCursor.js:144
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692840+00:00 app[web.1]: QueryCursor.prototype.map = function(fn) {
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692841+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692841+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692841+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'map' of object '#<QueryCursor>'
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692842+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cursor/QueryCursor.js:144:27)
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692842+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692842+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:10)
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692843+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692843+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692843+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692844+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692844+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:12:21)
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692844+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692844+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:10)
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692845+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-19T12:38:54.692845+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v17.5.0
2022-02-19T12:38:54.845812+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-02-19T12:38:55.309883+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-02-19T12:38:56.377269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=i-book-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=bc0cecd2-3197-43c3-9b15-6adbfa62943a fwd-6adbfa62943a fwd="150.129.159.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-19T12:38:57.014602+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=i-book-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=26338aa4-0e9b-41d4-b2b4-9cf32b-41d4-b2b4-9cf32ab946fa fwd="150.129.159.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-19T12:40:27.841439+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=i-book-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=9ecc5d99-e1fe-47cc-815c-ffde34a9568b fwd-ffde34a9568b fwd="150.129.159.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-19T12:40:28.357238+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=i-book-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=2d493654-9b7c-40f7-9e35-073c3c-40f7-9e35-073c3b950e51 fwd="150.129.159.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is my index.js file

```
const connectToMongo = () => { require('./db') };
const express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
connectToMongo();
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config();

const app = express()
// app.use(cors())
app.use(cors({
  origin: "*",
}));
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
https://runkit.com/

app.use(express.json())


app.use('/api/auth/', require('./routes/auth'))
app.use('/api/notes', require('./routes/notes'))



app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`i-book backend app listening at http://${port}`)
})
```

Please let me know, if I should more details from my side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/11377) in GitHub, it's a problem with node latest release v17.5.0 and mongoose that hasn't been addressed yet.

in order to temporary fix this issue change Nodejs engine version in the `package.json` file like this :

```
"engines": { "node": ">=12.0.0 <17.5.0" }
```

Note: you need to deploy your app again in order to reinstall Nodejs.

Comment: I have already changed my node version to 14.0.0, should I change it to 12.0.0?

Comment: I recommend you to use the same code that I mentioned because when I added it to my project node 17.4.0 has been installed and the Issue was fixed. It's not clear which version of node will satisfy your project needs and it doesn't make sense to find either, so using a lower version also can make errors on runtime too.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try

Comment: You need to install node 16.14.0 LTS version, my error was solved after installing it

Answer (score 0):

Node 17.6.0 fixes this, if you are using experimental features like built-in `fetch`

Comment: It didn't fix it for me.

Comment: I am facing this issue in node 18 :(

Comment: Have you updated mongoose?